# Marklogic cross database saving

Tags: marklogic

I have one scheduler script which is running on one database (DUMMY1) and wants to save output XML into another database (DUMMY2). Both the database is on same server. I am getting error 'XDMP-PLACEKEYSLOCKING' while doing so.

Could you help to find out how to resolve this problem? Is I am doing any wrong practice?

Comment: Can you share some code? That would help. Sounds like you are using a specific locking strategy. Did you change particular server or database settings?

Answer (score 2):

The error code [XDMP-PLACEKEYSLOCKING](https://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-PLACEKEYSLOCKING?q=XDMP-PLACEKEYSLOCKING) "Fast locking cannot be used with place keys" implies that a call to `xdmp:document-insert` is using the optional `$forest-ids as xs:unsignedLong*` parameter, and the target database is configured to use fast locking. Fast locking is usually good, so I would drop the `$forest-ids` parameter from `xdmp:document-insert`. That means the database will decide which forest to use, and that's usually what you want.

The other option is to change the database configuration to use strict locking.